# Chart.js isn't able to read elements from php as label

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I tried creating a table that gets its data from a mySQL database. Everything works fine except when I try to use time as labels for the graph.
Here is the code for the PHP:

```
<?php
// set arrays
$temp = array();
$humi = array();
$id = array();
$chronos = array();
// get
$query = "SELECT * FROM temp_humi";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
// transfer arrays
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp[] = $row["temp"];
    $humi[] = $row["humi"];
    $id[] = $row["id"];
}

// set variables
$res1;
$res2;
$res3;
$res4;
$len1 = count($temp);
$len2 = count($humi);
$len3 = count($id);
// input elements into variables
for($x = $len1 - 10; $x < $len1; $x++) {
    $res1 .= $temp[$x] . ', ';
}
for($x = $len2 - 10; $x < $len2; $x++) {
    $res2 .= $humi[$x] . ', ';
}
for($x = $len3 - 10; $x < $len3; $x++) {
    $res3 .= $id[$x] . ', ';
}
//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
// set time
$date = date("H:i:s");
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - 20;
// iterate time into array
for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++) {
    $time = $time + 2;
    $date = date("H:i:s", $time);
    array_push($chronos, $date);
}
// iterate timesinto variables
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
    $res4 .= $chronos[$x] . ', ';
}
// trim last comma
$res1 = rtrim($res1, ', ');
$res2 = rtrim($res2, ', ');
$res3 = rtrim($res3, ', ');
$res4 = rtrim($res4, ', ');
?>
```

I used arrays to input all the data from the mySQL database then put the elements of an array into a variable so that i can call it in the chart as values for the data and the label.
While this is my code for the chart in another php file:

```
<script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [<?php echo $res4; ?>],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Temperature',
                    fill: false,
                    data: [<?php echo $res1; ?>],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointBackgroundColor: [...]
                }, {
                    label: 'Humidity',
                    fill: false,
                    data: [<?php echo $res2; ?>],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(54,162,235,1)'],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointBackgroundColor: [...]
                }]
            }
        });
    </script>
```

When I try to use the ids as the value for the labels (the one named as $res3) , it works just fine. But when I try to use the time as labels ($res4), the page becomes empty.

Please help me. I tried turning the time values as strings by using (string)$var and strval($var) because I think it's because time is not a string but it didn't work.
Please help. I just started using Chart.js

Comment: What is the output of `<?php echo $res4; ?>`?

Comment: This is the output:
16:44:04, 16:44:06, 16:44:08, 16:44:10, 16:44:12, 16:44:14, 16:44:16, 16:44:18, 16:44:20, 16:44:22

Comment: It changes base on the current time.

Comment: Your count of `$res3` and `$res4` must be same. Are you sure count of `$res1`, `$res2`, and `$res3` is same as `$res4` i.e. 10.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've shared that PHP code. Have you already determined the data format expected by Chart.js and you've having difficulties generating that exact output?

Comment: you should always add quotes to php variables

Comment: Sir akshaypjoshi, what do you mean by the count of $res3 and $res4 ?

Comment: I think the expected value of the labels for the Chart.js is a list of strings separated by a comma. My problem is that the list of ids which is $res3 works but not $res4 which is a list of time

Comment: Sir Jelle Botman, do you mean like $'res4', like so?

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the output is not an integer, but a time ("16:44:04"), you can not place it inside an array without quotes.

```
$res4 .= '"'.$chronos[$x] . '", ';
```

As a more general approach, I don't suggest you to use string concatenation but PHP arrays and then implode them. This avoids having to trim the last comma.

```
$res1 = [];
$res2 = [];
$res3 = [];
$res4 = [];
$len1 = count($temp);
$len2 = count($humi);
$len3 = count($id);
// input elements into variables
for($x = $len1 - 10; $x < $len1; $x++) {
    $res1[] = $temp[$x];
}
for($x = $len2 - 10; $x < $len2; $x++) {
    $res2[] = $humi[$x];
}
for($x = $len3 - 10; $x < $len3; $x++) {
    $res3[] = $id[$x];
}
//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
// set time
$date = date("H:i:s");
$time = strtotime($date);
$time = $time - 20;
// iterate time into array
for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++) {
    $time = $time + 2;
    $date = date("H:i:s", $time);
    array_push($chronos, $date);
}
// iterate timesinto variables
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
    $res4[] = '"'.$chronos[$x].'"';
}
?>
```

And then

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [<?php echo implode(",", $res4); ?>],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Temperature',
                fill: false,
                data: [<?php echo implode(",", $res1); ?>],
                borderColor: ['rgba(255,99,132,1)'],
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointBackgroundColor: [...]
            }, {
                label: 'Humidity',
                fill: false,
                data: [<?php echo implode(",", $res2); ?>],
                borderColor: ['rgba(54,162,235,1)'],
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointBackgroundColor: [...]
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $res4 is an array of string, not date, so `labels: [<?php echo $res4; ?>],` will be like:

```
labels: [10:00:01, 10:00:02, 10:00:03, ...]
```

Javascript cannot read it because SyntaxError. You may need to put $res4 into an temporary array, then parse it to time before assign it to labels.
But before that, you need to quote your `$chronos[$x]` like this:

```
...
for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++) {
  $time = $time + 2;
  $date = date("H:i:s", $time);
  array_push($chronos, $date);
}
// iterate timesinto variables
for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {
  $res4 .= '"$chronos[$x]"' . ', ';
}
// trim last comma
$res1 = rtrim($res1, ', ');
$res2 = rtrim($res2, ', ');
...
```

And then in your front end

```
var temp = [<?php echo $res4 ?>];
// parse your time here
```

Hope this help.